# Swamping manifest file based on environment in deployment

Tags: angular, webpack, manifest

I would like to deploy a different manifest file to our staging and production environment. I wonder about using fileReplacement in Angular.json like this:

```
 "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "apps/store/src/manifest.webmanifest",
              "with": "apps/store/src/manifests/manifest.prod.webmanifest"
            }
          ],
         ....
      }
```

Is this possible? if not, how can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should try?

Comment: I need to do the same in my app. Any luck in the above code?

Comment: I can't make the fileReplacements work with the manifest. Don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as nobody finds a proper answer to my question. I like to share my workaround:

Use NPM Scripts:

Package.json:

```
"manifest:prod": "cp ./apps/store/src/manifests/manifest.prod.webmanifest ./apps/store/src/manifest.webmanifest",
```

In Gitlab Ci:

```
 script:
    - npm install -g @angular/cli
    - npm install
    - npm run manifest:prod
```